# Can I add active class when url starts a string in react Navlink?

Tags: reactjs, navigation

How do I add an active class in react navlink when url starts with a "/teacher/create/" string?

Answer (score 1):

```
<NavLink to={"/teacher/create/"} exact activeClassName={this.props.location.pathname.startsWith("/teacher/create/") && "activeLink"}>{title}</NavLink>
```

and add css:

```
.activeLink {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<NavLink to={"/teacher/create/2"} exact activeClassName={this.props.location.pathname === "/teacher/create/2" && "activeLink"}>{title}</NavLink>
```

and add css:

```
.activeLink {
    color: red;
}
```

**react-router-dom: "^4.1.2"**

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how the other solutions above work but in my case I had no access to this.props.location. You can do this by trying something like that:

```
export const LooseNavLink = props => (
  <NavLink {...props} isActive={(match, location) => location.pathname.startsWith(props.to.pathname)}/>
)
```